# populate the database in oracle (sqlplus)

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, sqlplus

I have a database with a bunch of tables and I want to populate the database using the SQL insert command. Now I am new to this so cut me some slack. Now here is an example:

I have a table like this

```
 TECH PERSONNEL (pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, expertise, office phone)
```

Where fname is first name, and lname is last name. And I want to put in

```
table TECH_PERSONNEL 

pplSoft  fname     lname    pittID  expertise        office_phone  expYears  supervisor


1110001  Bob       Hoffman  bh1     Unix systems     412-624-8404  15        1110001

1110002  Terry     Wood     tw1     Hardware         412-624-8831  14        1110001
```

However there is many lines of data for that table would I have to put code such as

```
 INSERT INTO TECH_PERSONNEL pplSOFT ('1110001', '1110002');
```

after the declaration of my table? I'm just confused.

Comment: Are you asking how to use INSERT for a full record (row) or...something else?

Comment: im asking is that the right way to insert that? i mean is there a way to populate the entire text file by insert? will i have to put the insert ...... statements after i write my table like CREATE TABLE TECH_PERSONNEL (pplsoft NUMBER(10)....statements); INSERT INTO TABLE TECH_PERSONNEL pplsoft('102923');  -- is that right?

Comment: in my .sql file where i have implemented my entire list of tables, i have wrote DROP table ____ before each and table and commit; purge recyclebin; at the end of the file... what im asking is do i need to declare insert inside of that file? or do i do it from sql> statement..

Answer (score 3):

The basic INSERT statement is:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (list of fields) VALUES (list of values);
```

Given your example & not knowing how your fields are defined, a row could go in as such:

```
INSERT INTO TECH_PERSONNEL 
(pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, expertise, office phone, expYears, supervisor) 
VALUES
('1110001', 'Bob', 'Hoffman', 'bh1', 'Unix systems', '412-624-8404', '15', '1110001');
```

Then the next row, etc.  If you're looking to use import a csv or other type of file directly into Oracle, that's a different question.  I'm  not really following what you're asking, so this answer is just the basic "how to use INSERT".

Comment: Thank You jcmeloni... one last question tho... do i just enter that at sql>  or do i have to open my file up and enter that info? if i enter that at sql> insert will that put that data into my table always? .. stupid questions i know but this really is all new to me and im messing around with it

Comment: @user1196080 no prob. don't forget to upvote &/or accept answers that are helpful when you use Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my language,  I'm on a cellphone.

I would also like to know how to dynamically populate a table. The way you randomize tables with random selections of values in c/c++, i.e.

```
char src[]={'a','b','c'};
char tbl[1024];
    //populate dynamically
for(int i(0);i<sizeof(tbl)/sizeof(char);i++){
 tbl[i]=src[random()%(sizeof(src)/sizeof(char))];
}
```

How to do this type of thing in .sql scripts parsed by sqlplus?